# Django analog to Python's mutable set

Tags: django, django-models

I've searched through the Django tutorial but I wasn't able to find information on what was Django's analog to Python's mutable set.

My friend said it might have to do with the ManyToManyField but that seems too inefficient. Is there another way around ?

Answer (score 0):

As far as django concerned, there aren't any data structures available. You have to implement it by yourself, or find a code snippet. In your case particularly, I would recommend using a TextField as container, where you put items with a delimeter between. Then you decode it into a set after you retrieve it, perform some operations, and encode as a string again.